# Create a GPS Tracker Without Google Service

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am a new Android programmer. I started a project on Android Studio and I trying to make an application that shows the current position of the user on a map like Google Maps, but I am trying to make it without using the Google service, like the application on Google Play Store: "Real Time GPS Tracker".

If you have any idea on how to get started, that will be great.

Comment: u need to a map server to show where the user exactlly on the earth.create yours or use one of the them like google map ,or open street

Comment: thanks for your feedback , but how can i create something like that if you have an idea ?